# Why not relax the definition of perimeter to a.e. $C^1_c$ functions?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

We have the following definition of perimeter, freely available from your favourite text on geometric measure theory:

$P(E)=\sup\bigg\{\int_E \nabla \cdot \varphi(x)\,dx:\varphi\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n):|\varphi|\leq 1\bigg\}$

My question is, why not define perimeter using $\varphi\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)-a.e.$? We are constantly defining things up to null sets in geometric measure theory and this surely makes it easier when wanting to demonstrate the definitions validity for $C^1$-rectifiable sets. If $\nu_E(x)$ is the outer unit normal at $x$, then for any $C^1$-rectifiable set $E$ we can just let $\varphi(x)=\nu_E(x)$ where it exists and $0$ else. Then a straightforward application of the Gauss-Green/Divergence theorem gets us where we need to go.

Is it purely convention that perimeter is not defined this way or is there some subtlety that I am missing? Perhaps there is a subsequent definition/theorem that is more cumbersome if we include the $-a.e.$?

Comment: What's your exact definition of "$C^1$ almost everywhere"?  And have you checked whether the Cantor staircase function satisfies it?  That's the sort of thing we most obviously have to rule out.

Comment: The correct weakened condition is usually something like absolute continuity or membership in an appropriate Sobolev space, e.g. $W^{1,1}$.  However since $C^1_c$ is dense in $W^{1,1}$, the value of the supremum does not change when we do this, so it may be more convenient to keep the test functions in a more regular class.

Comment: I guess what I mean by $C^1-a.e.$ is indeed $W^{1,1}$. I can certainly see the simplicity of keeping the test functions in a more regular class when it comes to actually stating the definition. However, I feel that weakening the definition makes it easier to actually apply. From your comments it seems that you don't inherently see anything wrong with my alternative definition, rather that it is a matter of preference?